# How do I write SQL query results to a text file

Tags: powershell

I am executing a SQL query in PowerShell and I need to pass the results of that query to a txt file. How can I do it?

Actually this is my code:

```
$QUERY = "SELECT ID_ORDEN_COMPRA,COMPROBANTE_TRANSACCION FROM ORDEN_COMPRA";    
Write-Output $QUERY;
$DB_LIST = Invoke-Sqlcmd -AbortOnError -EncryptConnection -ConnectionTimeout $TIMEOUT -Database 'dbprod_itswebpay' -ServerInstance $SQL_SERVER_FULLNAME_SOURCE -Username $SQL_ACCOUNT_NAME_SOURCE -Password $SQL_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_SOURCE -Query $QUERY;
```

Comment: The result of query you need to pass to txt?

Comment: yes, the result of the query

Comment: you can add "> .\path_to_file.txt" at the end.

Comment: if it worked thanks

Comment: And while I'm looking at this example, if you are using `Write-Output $QUERY` for debugging purposes, you might want to use `Write-Debug` rather than push the query to the Output stream, but that's another conversation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was simple, Victor Silva gave me the solution

```
Get-Process | Out-File -FilePath C:\procesos.txt

$QUERY = "SELECT ID_ORDEN_COMPRA, COMPROBANTE_TRANSACCION FROM ORDEN_COMPRA WHERE  COMPROBANTE_TRANSACCION IS NOT NULL AND FECHA_PAGO_ORDEN_COMPRA <= '20180101 23:59:59'";    
Write-Output $QUERY;
$DB_LIST = Invoke-Sqlcmd -AbortOnError -EncryptConnection -ConnectionTimeout $TIMEOUT -Database 'dbprod' -ServerInstance $SQL_SERVER_FULLNAME_SOURCE -Username $SQL_ACCOUNT_NAME_SOURCE -Password $SQL_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_SOURCE -Query $QUERY;
```

Answer (score 0):

The "PowerShell" way to do this is to use the `Out-File` cmdlet, adding this line at the end:

```
$DB_LIST | Out-File "my-file-path.txt"
```

You should also consider setting the file encoding explicitly if you need it to be UTF8 (for example):

```
$DB_LIST | Out-File "my-file-path.txt" -Encoding UTF8
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are objects, so I would export it to csv (ascii):

```
$DB_LIST | export-csv dblist.csv
```

Note that out-file encodes in unicode by default.